# Has anyone claimed that the cartesian ego is a necessary condition to any mind?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, descartes

Has anyone claimed that the Cartesian ego, by which I mean the ability to reflect, from which I may be able to deduce that "I am", is a necessary component of any mind?

Comment: I am sure people claimed it just as anything; are you asking for a good argument for it?

Comment: Hegel mentions the cartesian ego in the *phenomenology* and he's a big fan of reflection.

Comment: Are you referring to "human" mind, or "any" mind?  If its is the latter, then you need to define"what is "a mind"?